# YTD Average in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

[image]

Need to calculate YTD Average and LYTD Average in DAX , Our Fiscal year starts from Apr.
So if my current day is 5th of the June 2017 then lytd_AVG would be from Apr to June would be 
(MTD Aprn 17) + (MTD May 17) + (MTD June 17)/3

and LYTD_AVG would be
(MTD Apr 16) + (MTD May 16) + (MTD June 16)/3

Assuming my current date is 06-03-2017, the YTD avg would be 60

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is given monthly (since you have no sample data), for YTD you should be able to use something that looks like this:

```
YTD Avg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table[Value]), DATESYTD(Table[Date], "03-31"))
```

The last argument specifies the year-end date ([Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634221.aspx)).

You can use the `SAMEPERIOODLASTYEAR` function for LYTD:

```
LYTD Avg = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table[Value]),
               SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DATESYTD(Table[Date], "03-31")))
```

---

**Edit:** Since your data is daily, we need to do a bit more work.

First, add month and year calculated columns to your table:

```
Month = MONTH(Table[Date])
FiscalYear = YEAR(MINX(DATESYTD(Table[Date], "03-31"), [Date]))
```

Then you will group by months in your measures:

```
YTD = AVERAGEX
          SUMMARIZE(Table1,
              Table1[Month],
              "MTDAmount", SUM(Table1[Amount])),
          [MTDAmount])
```

---

```
LYTD = AVERAGEX(
           SUMMARIZE(
               FILTER(ALL(Table1),
                   Table1[Month] IN VALUES(Table1[Month]) &&
                   Table1[FiscalYear] = MAX(Table1[FiscalYear]) - 1),
               Table1[Month],
               "MTDAmount", SUM(Table1[Amount])),
           [MTDAmount])
```

You should then be able to build tables like this:

[image: Fiscal YTD]

Comment: This  does not work for me, I have attached sample data for your reference.